# Animating an addition and/or removal of an element on a plot in Plot.ly

Tags: javascript, animation, plotly

I'm trying to generate plot.ly graphs that should animate a new data element as it's added to an existing graph or animate a data element if it's removed from the graph.

Currently I'm using the Plotly.newPlot function and my code looks like this:

```
Plotly.newPlot('chart', plottablePopulations, layout)
```

The format of my data is like this:

```
plottablePopulations = [array of populationData]

populationData = {
   mode: "lines"
   name: "Arab World"
   type: "scatter"
   uuid: ".some unique id."
   x: [...array of x data...]
   y: [...array of y data...]
}

layout = {
   autosize: true,
   height: someHeight,
   title: "population vs year"
   width: someWidth,
   xaxis: object of x axis properties
   yaxis: object of y axis properties
}
```

I want to be able to when the array of populationData changes have Plotly animate those. These changes are only if an element is added or removed from the array not a mutated element of the array.

I've looked over the plotly documentation on how to do this here: https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/

It seems to indicate that you have to have a previous state and then transition to a new state. The documentation seems to only indicate how to animate changing data values rather than how to animate new lines or animate removed lines.

As animation has only recently been added to Plot.ly I was wondering if someone might know how best to reanimate my graph.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if that's what you are looking for but once you press the button, there is a 60% chance of adding a new data point or removing a random one.

In both cases the graph is updated with an animation.

The only trick is recalculate the range for the x and y-axis every time the graph is updated.

The snippet is based on the first example [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/).

```js
var data = {
    x: [0, 1, 2],
    y: [0.2, 0.5, 1]}
Plotly.plot('graph', [{
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y,
    ids: data.x,
    line: {simplify: false},
    type: "scatter"
}]);


function randomize() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    if (rand > 0.4) {
        data.x.push(Math.max.apply(null, data.x) + 1);
        data.y.push(0.1 + 3 * Math.random());
    } else if (rand < 0.5 || data.x.length > 2) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (data.x.length + 1));
        data.x.splice(index, 1);
        data.y.splice(index, 1);
    }
    var layout = {
        xaxis: {
            range: [Math.min.apply(null, data.x), Math.max.apply(null, data.x) + 0.5]
        },
        yaxis: {
            range: [0, Math.max.apply(null, data.y)]
        }
    };
    Plotly.animate('graph', {
        data: [{ids: data.x}],
        layout: layout
    }, {
        transition: {
            duration: 1500,
            ease: 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="graph"></div>
<button onclick="javascript:randomize();">Randomize!</button>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```